# Trying to combine two arrays of data from pokeapi via an axios.get function in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, axios

I'm working on a project right now where I'm accessing pokemon data from PokeAPI with axios. I am only accessing a few points of data, and one of them is the pokemon type. If the pokemon I'm searching for has two types, it will return the types as separate arrays.

For example, if I search Pikachu, it returns with just one array, which is Electric, because pikachu only has one type. However, if I search for Gengar, it will return two arrays. One with poison, and one with ghost.

How can I combine these into a single array of types?

Here is my code :

```js
module.exports = {
  getPokemon: async (req, res) => {
    const { pokemon } = req.body;
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get(
        `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemon.toLowerCase()}`
      );
      const types = data.types.map((pokemon) => pokemon.type);
      console.log(types);
      party.push({
        name: data.name,
        sprites: data.sprites.front_default,
        types: data.types,
      });
      res.status(200).send(party);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).send("something went wrong");
    }
  },
};
```

And the response I get in the console :

```
name: "gengar"
sprites: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/94.png"
types: Array(2)
0:
slot: 1
type: {name: 'ghost', url: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/8/'}
[[Prototype]]: Object
1:
slot: 2
type: {name: 'poison', url: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/4/'}
```

Comment: can you please share what you are receiving as response to the request?

Comment: I don't think I understand what you're planning to do. Can you share what is the wanted response ?

Comment: My bad. I want to combine the two arrays into one.

Comment: you are not using the types variable, instead, you are creating the object with data.types